# how to change value of arguments in batch script

Tags: batch-file, dos

I tried to use the code below in order to set default values into %1 %2 and %3, but when I try to use them I get unexpected behavior, %1,%2 and %3 are zeros

Script:

```
    'IF [%1]==[] (
         SET /P isDefault=Value Missing, do you want to use default values 1,1,10?[y/n]
         IF %isDefault%==y (
             SET 1=1
             SET 2=1
             SET 3=10
     GOTO :CREATE
     )  
:CREATE
FOR /L %%A IN (%1,%2,%3) DO (
    netsh interface ipv4 add address "Local Area Connection 2" 169.254.89.%%A 255.255.0.0
)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that command line variables (as %1,%2 using as their substitutions) are not allowed to be modified. Instead use intermediate variables:

```
 IF ..
       set var1=1
       set var2=1
       GOTO :CREATE
 )    

 set var1=%1
 set var2=%2

:CREATE
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing something similar :) but having trouble getting dos to ECHO the intermediate variables.